# View one specific project using its ID

Tags: python, file-handling

I want to search the id that was inside the file and output its other information. Currently here is my code

```
with open("Inputdetails.txt", "r") as file:
            pick = input("Enter id: ")
            for line in file:
                if pick in line:
                    print(line)
```

and my text file looks like this:

```
Id: 1
Title: ExampleTitle
Size: 50
Priority: 1

Id: 2
Title: Example Title2
Size: 50
Priority: 2
```

I want to search for its Id and display related content.
EX 1:

```
  Enter a number to search: 1
```

The output will be:

```
  Id: 1
  Title: ExampleTitle
  Size: 50
  Priority: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Python File next() Method**

> Python file method next() is used when a file is used as an iterator, typically in a loop, the next() method is called repeatedly. This method returns the next input line, or raises StopIteration when EOF is hit.

```
print('Enter id:')
id = input()
InputText = 'Id: ' + id
with open('C:/Users/user/Desktop/test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if InputText in line:
            print(line)
            for i in range(3):
                print(next(f))
```

[image]